# Pytorch batchwise matrix vector rowwise multiplication

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am using pytorch.

If I have a matrix `M` of size `(d1, d2)` and a vector `V` of size `d2`, doing `M*V` gives me an output `OUT` of size `(d1, d2)`, where each row of `M` has been multiplied by `V`.

I need to do the same thing batch-wise, where the matrix `M` is fixed and I have a batch of `dB` vectors.

In practice, given a tensor `M` of size `(d1, d2)` and a tensor `V` of size `(dB, d2)`, I need to get as output `OUT` a tensor of size `(dB, d1, d2)`, so that `OUT[i] = M*V[i]`.

How can I efficiently get it with pytorch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple trick works for the problem:

```py
M.unsqueeze(0) * V.unsqueeze(1)
```

This does multiplications of tensors having shapes `(1, d1, d2)` and `(dB, 1, d2)` and you get the desired output having shape `(dB, d1, d2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Einstein Notation to achieve this:

```
torch.einsum('ij,bj->bij', M, V)
```

Comment: Wow, great I hadn't seen it yet!